# How to target CSS link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, head

I only have access to the back end of my CMS. They are loading the custom style sheet this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:481px)" href=".../css/custom/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

I need to remove the `media="(min-width:481px)"`. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript (I don't think the CMS uses jquery)?

Comment: Sure there's a way. Whether it would actually do anything is a different matter. The stylesheet will have been loaded (or not) before JavaScript has a chance to load. It might be a better idea to just load the stylesheet via JavaScript rather than messing with the existing `link` element. For that, there are many answers on SO, including: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9979415/215552

Comment: So what CMS is it, it would be easier to just solve the issue on the backend.

Comment: I've tried contacting the CMS provider who is 100% certain that removing the `media="(min-width:481px)"` can't be done.

Comment: So the people who made it, don't know how to edit it ?

Comment: Pretty much. They also thought me adding `!important` inside the CSS would let me override the `media="(min-width:481px)"`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not recommend messing with the elements of a link with JavaScript, but if you still want to do it, this should work:

```
document.querySelector('link[href=href=".../css/custom/styles.css"]').removeAttribute('media');
```

If you still want to do this, make sure to wait for css styles to load.

If you want to go with this solution for some reason and do it for all link tags, then this one is simple:

```
var linkList = document.querySelectorAll('link');

for(var i in linkList) {
linkList[i].removeAttribute('media');
}
```

Always use `.removeAttribute`, instead of using `setAttribute` to set the argument to `null`. That is generally bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, this is most likely the correct answer, unfortunately I also just discovered they strip out any custom JS...

Comment: You are welcome. If you have access to the server-side language files, you can do it there manually. That would be the best scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately its a very poorly designed CMS run by egomaniacs that are 100% convinced their way is the only way.